# Как добавить ведущие нули к hex?

Tags: c#

Преобразую число:

```
int num = 1155;
string end = Convert.ToString(num , 16).TrimStart('0'));
```

В `end` записывается результат `483`, а нужно получить **0**483

Comment: @andreycha, там не дубликат, так как описывает спецификаторы, а здесь ТС нужны форматы.

Comment: @Mirdin ох, да, вы правы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int num = 1155;
string end = num.ToString("X8"); // end = @"00000483"
```

[Строки стандартных числовых форматов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)